# OracleBulkCopy error (table or view does not exist)

Tags: sql, .net, oracle

I'm trying to copy datatable from sql server to oracle using OracleBulk Copy. However I'm getting the following error:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

For the line `orca_bulk_copy.WriteToServer(dt);`.

The code is as follows:

```
string sqlstring = "select POSITION_ID, POSITION_DESC  from T_CD_POSITION";
SqlDataAdapter o_SQLDataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlstring, sqlconn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
o_SQLDataAdaptor.Fill(dt);

//SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, sqlconn);
//SqlDataReader reader = scmd.ExecuteReader();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    OracleConnection oraconn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
    oraconn.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("orca conn established....");


    OracleBulkCopy orca_bulk_copy = new OracleBulkCopy(oraconn);

    orca_bulk_copy.DestinationTableName = "UHAMPTST.t_test_postion";
    orca_bulk_copy.BatchSize = 5000;
    orca_bulk_copy.BulkCopyTimeout = 10000;
    Console.WriteLine("hh");
    orca_bulk_copy.ColumnMappings.Add("position_id", "position_id");

    orca_bulk_copy.ColumnMappings.Add("position_desc", "position_desc");
    orca_bulk_copy.WriteToServer(dt); // <----- ORA-00942 error occurs here!!
    Console.WriteLine("hhdd");
    orca_bulk_copy.Close();
    orca_bulk_copy.Dispose();
```

I did try to find why this error is coming but did not get enough info on it.

Comment: Posting user names and passwords online is a bad idea.

Comment: Like the error suggests, do your source and destination tables exist?

Comment: @Colin'tHart Yes they do

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-00942 - Table does not exists error`, one of the main error, any novice SQL developer faces. Please check the below.

1) When you don't refer a table with a `SCHEMA` name, check whether a `PUBLIC SYNONYM` exists for it. If it doesn't or you cannot have a public synonym, either you have to explicitly specify the schema name as a prefix to the table, else the `USER_ID` you used to connect to the database has default access to that schema.

2) Check whether, you have `SELECT` privileges from the table you try to select and `INSERT/UPDATE` privilege to the table you try to copy to.

Comment: I am able to select and insert values to the table easily. I did use the schema name. But ill try with the synonym too.

Comment: Okay, also you may need to confirm the database user id, the app uses, to double check the table is accessible to that user id.

Comment: Yes the table is accessible. The problem is that when I use the command WriteToServer(DataTable dt) It throws an exception saying table or view does not exist.